# Traversing a binary tree

Tags: c#, java

Hi I am still learning C# and am trying to create an algorithe of binary tree traversal for learning purposes.I did the same thing in Java and I managed to make it work.I need to know if I can give a method a a parameter of Node.This is what I have so far:

```
public class Node<T>
{
        public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
}



public static void InOrder(Node<T> n)
        {
        }
```

The problem is at the InOrder parameter it tells me that I can not pass a parameter of Node because it can not resolve symbole T.In Java I used this syntax to make it work Node n but it seems the syntax differes in C#.

If that is the case then how can I use my curent class Node as a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the static method inside the class `Node<T>` and it will work.  Outside the class, it has no idea what T means.

Comment: This is only one of several possible options.  It certainly is possible to have the method outside of the class by making the method, or whatever class the method is in, generic.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append a `<T>` to your method name since it's outside the `Node` class.

```
 public static void InOrder<T>(List<T> n)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need the T type on your method like this:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public Node<T> Left { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Right { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public static void InOrder<T>(Node<T> n)
{
}
```